# Морфемный разбор глагола «начинать» и его форм

Tags: грамматика, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, чередования

*Начинать — начать — начнем*.

Здесь чередование корней *-нач-* и *-начин-*. Как показать, что в слове начинать *-ин-* не суфикс?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вот как членятся на морфемы приведенные вами слова:
на-чин-а-ть (или начин-а-ть — в таком случае приставка слилась с корнем, произошла [деэтимологизация](http://linguistics-konspect.org/?content=5770)), на-ч-а-ть (или нача-ть, причины см. выше), на-ч-н-ем (нач-н-ем).

В школьной традиции принята скорее версия в скобочках. Тогда в корне возникает чередование ***ин – а***. *-ин-*, как вы можете видеть, является частью корня, а вовсе не суффиксом.